# Aggregate function for previous value in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use the `aggregate()` function on the `mtcars` data frame:

```
aggregate(wt ~ carb + gear, mtcars, mean)
aggregate(wt ~ carb + (gear-1), mtcars, mean)
```

The above code gives me the same result. However, I expected results to differ since I am trying to group results by previous gear value (`gear - 1`).

I also tried using `sqldf()`:

```
sqldf("select carb, gear, avg(wt) from mtcars group by carb, gear")
sqldf("select carb, gear, avg(wt) from mtcars group by carb, gear-1")
```

What am I doing wrong?

The source data frame looks like this:

```
c1          HOUR_OF_DAY   c2
01A           0             1868987
01A          20         989799
06A          17         198787
06A          19             765876
06FD          18        866876
01A          23             8687689
07A          21             676689
01A          23             967689
```

I used:

```
df <- aggregate(c2 ~ c1 + HOUR_OF_DAY, source, mean)
```

What I am trying to do is calculate the previous hour of day as `group_by`. If the current hour is 0, the previous hour must be 23. If the current hour hour is 1, the previous hour should be 0, and so on.

```
For input as first row 01A, 0, 1868987
It should take 01A, 23, 967689
                  01A, 23, 8687689
```

And does average on c2 and returns `c1`, `Hour_of_day`, `average(c2)`
I hope this explains my problem.

Comment: It is not clear.  If we look at the `mtcars` data, the first 3 rows have 'gear' as 4 followed by 'gear' of 3.  Can you show the expected output?  The unique elements in 'gear' are `unique(mtcars$gear)
#[1] 4 3 5`

Comment: Changing the values uniformly doesn't change the grouping; the same sets of rows all have the same values (though those values are now different). What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Explained about my problem Thanks